# I want to be able to determine whether an exchange account has been set uo as a journal recipient

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In short, what i want to be able to do is find out if a mailbox is the one set up to be a journal recipient?

I have setup a Journal Recipient in exchange admin center for an account called compliance@xyz.com. (Via Servers\Database\ and then properties on the database and finally in the maintenance section)

I have another account bobsmith@xyz.com and johnsmith@xyz.com, who both send emails between them.

The journal account will track conversations between these to accounts.

I then have a service that connects to Exchange using EWS and reads a specified mail box.

bobsmith@xyz.com and johnsmith@xyz.com are standard mailboxes, so i have some code that will iterate the inbox and create then email(s) and extract the attachemnt(s), if any.

If i decied to connect using the compliance@xyz.com mailbox, is there a way using EWS, witnin a windows c# service, to find out if this mailbox is the journal recipient?

Hope what i am asking makes sence?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to determine if the Mailbox is a journal recipient as this is really only a Transport configuration. The Journal reports themselves are distinctive though

Comment: Thanks for responding Glen. i'll take a look and see what i can find, any suggestions what to look for and where? I tried looking in the header but not sure what to look for? I'm truly stuck!! I will try and compare a normal email with a journal report and see if i can distinguish a difference?

Comment: I don't have journaling enabled anywhere at the moment but if you look at one message using a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy or MFCMapi you should find what you need

Comment: Brilliant, ill look into it.